# Android Tween Animations clipped boundaries

Tags: android

I've been trying to figure out a good solution for this issue for a while, but have never been able to quote figure it out... So, hopefully someone can help me out or point me in the right direction since I've exhausted my Google quota for the next year.

Basically, what I want to accomplish is a ScaleAnimation of an individual view that, when Long Clicked, will expand and then contract to signify that it has been pressed.

That's all setup; no problem there.

The issue is that the ScaleAnimation is clipped by the parent of the view and does not extend into its parent. Here's the hierarchy:

```
Relative > 
    Relative >
        Linear >     (<-- The animation is cut at the outer bounds of this parent)
            View
```

I've tried adding android:clipChildren="false" and android:clipPadding="false", but neither of those solutions helped me actually animate outside the boundaries of the first parent.

I understand that tween Animations were designed to not extend beyond the boundaries of the View in which the animated View lies, but is it not possible and can be seen in things like Draggable Views?

Or am I just approaching this situation entirely wrong?

How can one actually animate beyond the boundaries of the first parent?

Thanks in advance for the help,
-Matt

Comment: With a hacky solution... I basically changed the parent layout to a FrameLayout and have a hidden Custom TextView z-positioned above the other content. When I need to call the animation, I give the TextView the same LayoutParams/background/text as the View I need to animate, set it to View.VISIBLE, animate it, and set it back to View.GONE when the animation has completed. I'll answer below I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I've been able to come up with, albeit hacky, still works.

The parent is a RelativeLayout and I have a hidden Custom TextView z-positioned above the other content. When I need to call the animation, I give the TextView the same LayoutParams/background/text as the View I need to animate, set it to View.VISIBLE, animate it, and set it back to View.GONE when the animation has completed:

```
public void doAnimation(final View v){      
    v.setId(5); 
    final CustomTextView animatorImage = (CustomTextView) ((MainActivity)mActivity).findViewById(R.id.pick_animator_image); // Our hidden TextView in the FrameLayout
    try{
        animatorImage.setBackgroundDrawable(v.getBackground());
        animatorImage.setText(((TextView)v).getText().toString());
        animatorImage.setTextColor(((TextView)v).getCurrentTextColor());
        animatorImage.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, ((TextView)v).getTextSize());
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());
    int[] windowLocation = new int[2];
    v.getLocationInWindow(windowLocation);

    params.leftMargin = (int) windowLocation[0];
    params.topMargin = (int) windowLocation[1] - ((MainActivity)mActivity).getSupportActionBar().getHeight() - getStatusBarHeight(); // Subtract the ActionBar height and the StatusBar height if they're visible

    animatorImage.setLayoutParams(params);
    animatorImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    ScaleAnimation scaleAnim = new ScaleAnimation(1f, 2.5f, 1f, 2.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    scaleAnim.setDuration(300);
    scaleAnim.setZAdjustment(Animation.ZORDER_TOP);
    scaleAnim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {

            ScaleAnimation scaleAnim2 = new ScaleAnimation(2.5f, 1f, 2.5f, 1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            scaleAnim2.setDuration(300);
            scaleAnim2.setZAdjustment(Animation.ZORDER_TOP);
            scaleAnim2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    animatorImage.clearAnimation();
                    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    animatorImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }

                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }});

            animatorImage.startAnimation(scaleAnim2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }});

    animatorImage.bringToFront();
    animatorImage.startAnimation(scaleAnim);
}
```

The XML hierarchy is:

```
RelativeLayout (parent)
    ViewGroup (main content body)
    TextView (hidden View to animate)
```

Just change "R.id.pick_animator_image" to whatever your TextView's ID is in the RelativeLayout and call that method with the View you want to animate, and this will fake it for you.